# How to kill response threads if user has navigated away from request page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

We have implemented an MVC version of Facebook's BigPipe framework and are running into memory spikes that seem to be related to BigPipe's threads hanging. These spikes are causing our production machines to restart every few hours. If you are unfamiliar with BigPipe, this is the basic gist:

[BigPipe is a fundamental redesign of the dynamic web page serving system. The general idea is to decompose web pages into small chunks called pagelets, and pipeline them through several execution stages inside web servers and browsers.](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919/)

It basically allows the client to request and render the page as pagelets become available rather than waiting for the whole response to come back. This is accomplished by flushing the response multiple times from multiple threads on the server side. We think the issue might be caused by people visiting our dashboard page (which uses bigpipe) but leaving the page before all pagelets are served. We believe this may leave these threads hanging without anywhere to actually send the response.

**Is there a method to kill code execution if a client stops waiting for the response? Or is there a way to set timeouts on threads that hang?**

Answer (score 0):

The only hint *(that I know of)* for detecting this condition is querying [`Reponse.IsClientConnected`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.isclientconnected(v=vs.110).aspx)